# responsive gridview layout for wider and taller thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create gridview layout. But having difficulties while showing image in that. Some images are longer some are wider due to this my overall design is looking ugly.

[image]

You can see that in screenshot. 
I want they stay in same row/box.

HTML

```
<div class="my-gallery thumb" id="grid" data-pswp-uid="1">
<!-- ngRepeat: imageUrl in images --><div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 ng-scope">

    <figure>
    <a href="87.jpg" class="thumbnail " data-size="800x600"> 
    <img src="a.jpg" class="img-responsive " ng-src="a.jpg" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
    </figure>

</div><!-- end ngRepeat: imageUrl in images --><div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 ng-scope">

    <figure>
    <a href="78.jpg" class="thumbnail " data-size="800x600"> 
    <img src="b.jpg" class="img-responsive " ng-src="b.jpg" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
    </figure>

</div><!-- end ngRepeat: imageUrl in images --><div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 ng-scope">

    <figure>
    <a href="70.jpg" class="thumbnail " data-size="800x600"> 
    <img src="c.jpg" class="img-responsive " ng-src="c.jpg" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
    </figure>

</div><!-- end ngRepeat: imageUrl in images --><div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 ng-scope">
```

**CSS**

```
div.thumb {
     float: left;
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    position: relative;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;

}
```